# How to change of Firebase Project for iOS app

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to shift to another firebase project and run it on my iPhone. However, when I log in using my email id and password, the app seems to be connected with the previous firebase project and not the new one. I need to connect my ios app to the new firebase project. By the way, I'm using flutter and android studio. I have already put the correct bundle id and downloaded the googleinfo.plist for the new firebase project in flutter project under the ios folder. Kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Check bundle id of the new project in firebase.
- If bundle id on firebase same the your project bundle id, remove GoogleService-Info.plist.
- Download GoogleService-Info.plist of the new project in firebase, open Xcode and than click add file to runner
- Choose new GoogleService-Info.plist.
- flutter clean
- flutter run

Comment: Thanks will do this and let you know if it worked

Comment: will let you know if I have further questions regarding this issue

Answer (score 0):

Delete .firebasesrc file and your good to go

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).